# How to integrate Linkedin SDK in app to Login & share using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn SDK in iOS using swift

I found the below code in objective-C

I am very new to swift,
I tried to convert this code in swift but it doesn't work.
Plz suggest me How can I convert this below code in swift.
or how can I integrate Linkedin Sdk for login & share through my app using swift..

```
enter code here
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState){
 NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
 LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
 NSLog(@"Session  : %@", session.description);

 [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
                                        success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {

 NSData* data = [response.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

 NSString *authUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", [dictResponse valueForKey: @"firstName"], [dictResponse valueForKey: @"lastName"]];
 NSLog(@"Authenticated user name  : %@", authUsername);
 [self.lblAuthenticatedUser setText: authUsername];

  } error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
   NSLog(@"Error  : %@", apiError);
  }];
  } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Error called  : %@", error);
 }];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to authenticate a user via LinkedIn, using SwiftyJSON library to parse the response. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON
As of May 2015 LinkedIn limited access to their API allowing only basic profile fields/email to be accessed. You also need to set the basic permissions for r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress under your app in the developer console in order for this to work.

Hope this helps

```
@IBAction func connectWithLinkedIn(sender: AnyObject) {

  let url = NSString(string:"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,industry,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,headline,summary,publicProfileUrl,specialties,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),pictureUrls::(original),location:(name))?format=json")

    let permissions: [AnyObject] = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION]

    LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth(permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (success) -> () in
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url as String, success: {
                response in
                print(response)
                print("successfully signed in")

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in

                    if let dataFromString = response.data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                        let result = JSON(data: dataFromString)


                        LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                        //Do something with the response for example
                        var picURL: String!

                        for stringInArray in result["pictureUrls"]["values"]{

                            let value = stringInArray.1.stringValue
                            print(value)
                            picURL = value
                        }
                       print(result["pictureUrls"]["values"].arrayValue)
                       print(result["specialties"].stringValue)


                        }


                })

                }, error: {
                    error in

                    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
                    LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    //Do something with the error
            })
        }


        print("success called!")


        }, errorBlock: { (error) -> () in
            print("%s", "error called!")

            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
            LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()
    })




}
```

Comment: hello, app is asking about linkedin app installed on device - can you suggest way login without linkedin app installed?

Comment: I suggest creating a webview login

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer this snippet for LinkedIn sharing:

Paste it into the valid session condition `LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession()`

**Swift 3x**:

```
let url: String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"

let payloadStr: String = "{\"comment\":\"YOUR_APP_LINK_OR_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE\",\"visibility\":{\"code\":\"anyone\"}}"

let payloadData = payloadStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, body: payloadData, success: { (response) in

print(response!.data)

}, error: { (error) in

print(error as! Error)

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "aomething went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(action)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


})
```

Comment: How to open Linkedin share dialog?

Comment: @amirt I think Linkedin doesn't provide a default dialogue box. You can either create your own if you want and don't forget to upvote only if this snippet solved your problem. ;)

Comment: I have already use above code, but i don't get any success response and can't see the share data over my linkedin page.

Comment: Have you added LIAppid and also the query scheme in your .plist file??

Comment: yes i have added, Linkedin login is perfect working but not share.

Comment: when i hit share button, i got `2017-05-29 11:29:45.178 MyAssignmentHelp[1643:112886] appId=myApId
2017-05-29 11:29:45.178 MyAssignmentHelp[1643:112886] no valid session`

Comment: Is it necessary to install Linkedin app for create the session and all

Comment: Yes, you need to create one condition for this if LinkedIn is installed or not. If yes then it will share on LinkedIn. And have you written the permission in code? like: LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION. Or maybe you have to create session again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145348/discussion-between-anurag-sharma-and-ami-rt).

Comment: Hello Anurag I am facing same issue can ypu please help me , while sharing text gettting error  Domain=LISDKErrorAPIDomain Code=403 "(null)"

Comment: Yes, what are the parameters are you sending? And did you setup everything on the developerLinkedin account?

Comment: I think your API URL link is not correct (general guess)